# Apollo Client - Calling concat on a terminating link, which will have no effect

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have the following Apollo Links:

```
 const link = ApolloLink.from([
    serializingLink,
    httpAuthLink,
    queueLink,
    retryLink,
    errorLink,
    uploadLink,
    httpLink
  ]);
```

And they are all with the correct setup 
After adding a new link, that error started to appear in the console:

```
Error: You are calling concat on a terminating link, which will have no effect
```

By reading another issue, I saw that this can be related with the order of the links inside of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A terminating link is one that actually sends the request and receives the response. There should only ever be one terminating link at the very end of your chain. In the code you posted, there's at least two terminating links -- `uploadLink` and `httpLink`. Assuming `uploadLink` was created using `createUploadLink`, there's no need to include both it and `httpLink`. `UploadLink` is a drop in replacement for `HttpLink`, so you can just remove the `httpLink` alltogether.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm a beginner with GraphQL and I didn't know about terminating links

Comment: Check out the docs here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/overview/

Comment: @DanielRearden I've been looking for this answer for hours, thank you ver much!

Comment: This worked for me. Many thank. By removing `httpLink` and using only `uploadLink ` is a right way.